# excel formulas - auto update SUM formula based on range, when rows added/deleted

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with a SUM formula (in E15), which adds together the values entered in the 4 cells below (E16:E19). Below that list (E20 onwards) is another SUM formula that adds together the next 4 cells (E21:E24). This repeats throughout the workbook to calculate sub-totals of a range of items, however, I will need to add and delete rows so the total number of cells to be added to each formula will not always be 4.

How can I ensure the SUM formula updates itself to include all of the values entered below when a new row is added or one deleted? Could the formula search cells below and stop when it reaches the next formula?

EG:
Formula in E15 =SUM(E16:E19)
Then I may want to add three rows at E16, delete one somewhere in the middle..
Formula in E15 now reads =SUM(E19:E21), but I need it to read =SUM(E16:E21).

This needs to happen automatically so users don't have to manually amend the SUM range every time.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: So you want it to always go from the row below the formula to the next formula?  Is there a common title in another column like "SUBTOTAL"?

Comment: Thats right Scott. The SUM formula and it's value's to be added are all in the same column, the name of this column (written in E5) is "INITIAL SUMS". The common title in the cell adjacent to each SUM formula (one cell to the left) just reads "Sub-total".

Comment: In your comments to both answers you stated that mine worked and the other did not, but you mark the other as correct.  Was this an error or did something not work in my formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about users modifying the workbook, you can still sum the range but protect the worksheet. It's a lot easier and sounds like what you need.

I don't know your version of Excel, but you should be able to find it under the Review tab.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but users need to be able to modify the workbook to create a custom set of rows in each range. These then need values input next to them, then the formula automatically calculates everything in that list into sub-total value, that the rest of the workbook calculates further equations from.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in every sub-total cell in Column E:

```
=SUM(INDEX(E:E,ROW()+1):INDEX($E:$E,ROW() + IFERROR(MATCH("Sub-total",INDEX(D:D,ROW()+1):$D1004006,0)-1,MATCH("Project Total",INDEX(D:D,ROW()+1):$D1004006,0)-1)))
```

It will set the area from the row beneath the formula to the next time that `Sub-total` in Column D

As per your comment I ammended the formula to include a look for the words "Project Total" In Column D.  If the value in Column D that indicates the sum of all the subtotals in Column E is spelled different make the change to what it is .

Comment: Scott, so far working like a dream, thanks. However I've encountered a new issue.

At the end of the workbook (column E) is a formula that adds together all of the sub-total values to give a "Project Total" (E83). Directly below this, is a value taken from another worksheet (E84, "Variations"), then below that is the "Project Total inc. Variations" which =SUM(E83+E84).

With your formula you provided, I am getting a circular reference between E78 (the last Sub-total) and E83 (the Project Total). The Project Total (E83) is not showing the value of the sub-totals added together..?

Comment: @Jimbo see edit.  Change `Project Total` to the verbiage in Column D of the Project Total value row.

Comment: Ok, and if there was a range with a break (row of blank cells) before the next entry of "Sub-total" - can I stop the search when it finds the first blank cell?

I tried a few variations of my own but to no avail.

Comment: @Jimbo the sum will ignore the blank cells.  Is there a reason you do not want to include it?  If so: Is there always a blank row between subtotals?

Comment: The formula does ignore blank cells which is correct, however there is a separate 'section' at the top of the sheet which has it's own subtotal. This is separated from the rest of the sub-total list by two clear rows of blank cells.

I have amended the code to from -1 to -3 at the end of each Match formula, which seems to work.

Comment: @jimbo then please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.