# Detect specific strings in excel/google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have the following data in excel / google spreadsheet,column A contains values separated by a, and this column will be updated everyday with new data. Column B shows the sum for all values separated by a's. For instance, there are two values between the 1st a and 2nd a, therefore the sum for these two = 2+2=4. There are three values between the 2nd a and the 3rd a, therefore the sum for these three = 3+2+4=9.

[image]

I am just wondering if I could write a function in column B to automatically detect where a is and then do the sum for all future data. It's like doing the loop thing in programming.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231627/excel-formulas-auto-update-sum-formula-based-on-range-when-rows-added-deleted/39232257?noredirect=1#comment65833077_39232257

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you never have more than 100 rows of numbers between "a" the following formula works =IF(A9="a",SUM(OFFSET(A10,0,0,IFERROR(MATCH("a",A10:A107,0),100)-1,1)),"")` in cell B3

Comment: Still works. Did you try it? The match takes care of any number of rows up to 100.

Comment: @atclaus thx! it works like a charm! just to mention that by using your equation, the last row in column A needs to be "a" in order to get the sum for the last group of values between the last a and the second last a. But thx a lot!!

Comment: @NickLiu you are welcome. Just edited my answer with the solution to the final a issue. Had solved it but copied the wrong formula!

Comment: @pnuts   what OP wants is pretty comprehensible, at least to some ppl. I dont see any need to post when u dont understand the question.